# How to view nodejs express console.logs running on nginx web server

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

Is it possible to view the console.logs from an express server running on nginx web server?

If so how/where would these files be located?

I've looked in /var/log/nginx at the assess.log and error.log files but those seem to be different.

It's currently impossible to debug a 502 Bad Gateway error on my web api

Answer (score 0):

If you are running nginx web server with a pm2 process manager the answer is

`~/.mp2/logs`